# Can one make an A4 printer print on longer seamless paper strips?

Tags: printer, printing

Some printers marketed as A3 printers (29.7cm x 42cm), like the Epson Stylus T1110 in Latin America, are reported to print pages up to 111cm.

A friend of mine needs to print teaching materials on 15cm x 50cm strips, has anyone managed to do anything similar on cheap A4 inkjet printers?

The point is to save time from lots of cutting & pasting he currently does.

Comment: Why not adjust the page size accordingly before printing? Won't that work?

Comment: depends on the model , though most printer would show paper jam if the paper doesnot exit after a specified period

Comment: Some printer drivers allow custom sizes but those sizes are restricted, I will try and check some models and post results.